# ContentDistribution FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

Tags: soql, contentdocument, dmlexception, field-integrity-exception

I'm trying to insert a record to `ContentDistribution` object using the
following:

Here is the doc says: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm?search_text=ContentDistribution

ExpiryDate  Type: dateTime

```
ContentDistribution cdl = new ContentDistribution();
cdl.ContentVersionId = 'id goes here...';
cdl.Name = 'PublicShare';
cdl.ExpiryDate = Datetime.now().addDays(1);
insert cdl;
```

If I don't provide the `ExpiryDate` then I was able to insert the record, I'm not sure what ExpiryDate is expecting.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You must specify the expiry option
> if an expiry date is set.: [ExpiryDate]

Comment: I have seen a similar issue in past. Can you try setting ContentDistribution.PreferencesExpires = true; and confirm if that fixes the issue

Comment: yep the error is very confusing, after I try the `PreferencesExpires = true` then I was able to insert the record, please post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set PreferencesExpires as true to fix the error

```
ContentDistribution cdl = new ContentDistribution();
cdl.ContentVersionId = '0696F00000U3VzSQAV';
cdl.Name = 'PublicShare';
cdl.PreferencesExpires = true; 
cdl.ExpiryDate = Datetime.now().addDays(1);
insert cdl;
```

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm?search_text=ContentDistribution),

> PreferencesExpires: When true, access to the shared document expires on
> the date that’s specified by ExpiryDate.